# Function and Arguments

Tags: coding-style, parameter-passing

What does [Robert C Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) meant by saying

> Output arguments are harder to understand than input arguments. When
>   we read a function, we are used to the idea of information going in to
>   the function through arguments and out through the return value. We
>   don’t usually expect information to be going out through the
>   arguments. So output arguments often cause us to do a double-take.

in his book '[The Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)' in chapter 3 Functions when he is talking about arguments in functions and which argument is he referring to here?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a longer quote with more context for those who don't have a copy of the book please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that we shouldn't have function that modifies input arguments. 
As an example (from "Clean Code"):

`public void appendFooter(StringBuffer report)`

He says report is rather *output* argument here because this function 
modifies it. Much better would be to have *Report* object and call:

`report.appendFooter();`

or instead of:

`public void changeContactDetails(Person person)`

do

`person.changeContactDetails()`